# Error in Dynamic ConnnectionString in Web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I want to change Initial catalog in web.config according to value of dropdown list at the time of login and other things will be remain same like user id, data source, password etc.

It's working fine for me but as We all know "name" attribute can not be same in connectionstring. So I am changing the name attribe according to each connectionString.

But the main problem is that I have defined Connection in every page inside the class like this..

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString);
```

So the "name" attribe should be dynamic according to connectionstring in web.config. So I tried to use Session Variable in the place of "name" attribute in each page like this....

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Session["ConnectionName"]].ConnectionString);
```

But Unfortunately Session does not work inside class. So what is the solution ?

Comment: *I have defined Connection in every page inside the class*. Why not create a separate data access layer for this purpose.

Comment: Hi @SuprabhatBiswal, Thanks for your reply.    I don't have much experience for it. Is there any solution for my current scenario ?

Comment: How many `Initial catalog` are there in your current project?

Comment: No limit. Actually User will create financial year and according to fin. year project will create database then a new connectionstring will be created according to new database.

Comment: In that case please check these references, Hope this help you out [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/755380/Dynamic-Connection-String) and [AspSnippet](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Programmatically-Add-or-Update-Connection-String-in-ASPNet-WebConfig-File.aspx)

Comment: I already checked these references but my problem is different. I just want to know. How can I change "name" attribute dynamically in each page.

Comment: That's what i said it earlier, If you could separate your data layer from business layer then you could pass the connection string key selected from the drop down as a parameter in callable function.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can have a master database where you can maintain all the connections/ core part of your project based on your constraints (like year, etc.,).

Now you can pull the connection string from the master database.
There are many other scenarios to achieve this but based on your requirement creating  a master database is a better approach.

Hope this will help you.